# How to watch the struct of http package content in mac os?

Tags: http, package, gzip, flurry

I want to see what data does Flurry send.

So I using the charles(a package catcher tools) to catch the package which Flurry send. But the http package may compressed in Gzip format(I'm not sure. I can see the Accept-Encoding is "Gzip, deflate" ). so I can't see the real struct of the package.

I didn't want to know the struct of http, but the http content struct. Is there anyone can give me some tip or introduct some other tools in Mac to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Flurry uses a proprietary content structure which will not be easy to parse out for your own reading.

Sorry if that causes you an inconvenience.

Disclaimer: I work at Flurry